# IBM Notes Scheduled agent does not execute

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I wrote an agent that runs every 1:00 AM daily, but fails to execute the routine mysteriously. I've checked the agent log and saw that it ran and ends without any error. What I've been thinking about is when I trigger the agent or ran it manually it executes the routine I coded successfully and not when it is scheduled. I really don't know what's the issue there, thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few things to try

1. Check the trigger property on the agent and set it to run on All documents or change it to None. Test both scenarios. There are some issues with this setting.
2. When you run an agent manually from the notes client or designer you are running it using the credentials from you id file. When running it scheduled you use the credentials from the server.
   Make sure your server have enough access to perform what your script does. There is also a setting in the agent for increasing what the script is allowed to perform.

If you have access to the server console you can trigger the agent to run on server using the command: tell amgr run "database.nsf" 'agentname'

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Thomas, my current agent setting is the default, I just changed the schedule field. I'll be testing your suggestion and get back to you right away. I'm using the servers administrator ID so i think it has all the permission that is needed to run the agent. I also signed the agent using the same admin ID.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and it seems that all is working fine, the agent runs as scheduled. Thank you very much. I encountered a new issue but I think its a different topic, i'll post a new one again.

Comment: great, so what what the solution?

Comment: Aww.. Sorry if I didn't mention the solution. Number 1 work for me. I don't know who messed with the code but there are some changes on the scripts and settings and one of them is the Target property of the agent. Setting it to All Documents in the server solved the issue.